# How to beat the Rat King in the eastern room?

Tags: shadowrun-hong-kong

When you get belowdecks in the Sinking Ship mission, there's a point where you come to a door and get one of those video game warnings, "the Rat King is in there, if you go in you'll set off the final battle for this mission".  So I didn't go in, because there was still stuff to do.  Eventually I ended up in the eastern room where the Matrix terminal is, and used it to arm the scuttling charges.  However, this causes the Rat King to show up and attack.

Partway through the battle, the Rat King raises an invincible magical shield.  It's implied that you need to get Gobbet to steal the Shiny Object from the Rat King's room in order to break the shield, but I'm not in the Rat King's room, and the doors out of the room I'm in are locked.  So how do I beat the Rat King?  (Or is it unwinnable in this situation?  I've already run into one bug where being in the wrong room when combat locks down the doors ends up making it impossible to progress, so it wouldn't surprise me to find a second one.)